# Excel Removed Attachments when trying to Dynamically Create a new Module

Tags: excel, vba

I have this little VBA module that I call from one workbook to update all Excel Workbooks in a given folder.  By update I mean it copies a module called GetActiveXControlValues and then runs this macro on each workbook in that folder.  Now when I run this on my machine everything works fine.  When my co-worker runs this same code with the same files, they gets a surprise after copying the module.  When you go to look at the workbook that should have the new module called 'GetActiveXControlValues', instead there is no module by that name, instead it is called 'Module1'.  In addition, when you look inside the new module it says 'Attachment has been removed' in red.  I checked and my co-worker has the exact same Security Settings in Excel 2010 as I have.

I have enable all Macros and Trust VBA Project Object Model.  I have Prompt me for enabling all ActiveX controls.  I have Disable Trusted Documents unchecked and all the boxes on the Protected View tab.  Anyone seen this before or have an idea what I can try to troubleshoot?

### Sample Code:

```
Sub CopyModuleAndExecuteIt()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFullMacroName As String

    SetFolder

    sPath = sExcelFolder
    ChDir sPath
    sFile = Dir("*.xls") ' File Naming Convention

    Do While sFile <> "" ' Start of LOOP

        ' Open each Excel File in the specified folder
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFile) ' SET BP HERE!
        Sleep (1000)

        ' Unprotect the Documents using SendKeys Hack
        UnprotectVBADocument

        ' Import the GetActiveXControlValues Module into the Workbook
        wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("D:\GetActiveXControlValues.bas") ' SET BP HERE!

        sFullMacroName = "'" & wb.Name & "'" & "!" & wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("GetActiveXControlValues").Name & ".GetActiveXControlValues"

        ' Run the GetActiveXControlValues Macro
        Application.Run (sFullMacroName)

        ' Close the Workbook Saving Changes
        wb.Close True
        sFile = Dir
    Loop ' End of LOOP
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of .Bas, export the module as .TXT and then try to import that. Does it work?    wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("D:\GetActiveXControlValues.Txt")

Comment: Same result with .TXT extension.  It was was a good thing to try though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It could have been removed by a virus checker: check the log files

Comment: This is what I was thinking Chris.  I couldn't find any logs though (using Microsoft Forefront).

Answer (score 0):

If your co-worker has the exact same Security Settings in Excel 2010 as you have then the next thing that comes to my mind is the "Firewall". Check his firewall settings.

Comment: Hum, we are on the same network and the Excel is not accessing any network resources.  I'm not sure how the firewall would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I was working to create an *AddIn* trough *VBA* code, i wrote the code in a Excel worksheet when i save it, i saved as text like this:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module_Name"
```

And you have to be sure that you *.bas* file is actualy is plain text.

I was working to create an *AddIn* with *VBA* code, i wrote the code in a Excel worksheet when i save it, i saved as text like this:

```
Sub Superheroes()

Dim sBeg as string, sEnd as String, sCatwoman as String, sAntMan as String
Dim vCode As Variant

'' Here is where i put the name i want to call my module
sBeg = "Attribute VB_Name = ""VBA_BasFile""" + vbCrLf + _
        "Private Function fMix(sAnimal as String)as String "

sCatwoman = "Select case sAnimal"+ vbCrLf+ vbTab+"case ""cat"""+ _
            vbCrLf+ vbTab+ "fMix = ""Catwoman"""

sAntMan = vbCrLf+ vbTab+"case ""Ant"""+ vbCrLf+ vbTab+ "fMix = ""AntMan"""+ _
          vbCrLf+ "End Select"

sEnd = vbCrLf+ "End Sub"

vCode = Array(sBeg, sCatwoman, sAntMan, sEnd)

Workbooks.add

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vCode) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(vCode)

With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs path + "VBA_BasFile.bas", xlTextPrinter
    .Close False
End With

End Sub
```

With this i can *Call* any procedure or function in the *VBA_BasFile* when i importe to another Excel Workbook.